# Why is my RaycastHit2D is always returning true?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

This is the first time I use raycasting but for some reason it ALWAYS returns true? I did a debug.log as you can see in the script below and it always prints out the message I told it to write if it's true. I did set the playerlayer (layermask) to player in the inspector. Still returning true.

I set it to everything also, its still returning true. I even set the layermask to nothing and it's still returning true. I probably did the silliest mistake ever but I'm new to raycasting.

Here's the script

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LadderRayCast : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float size;
    public Player pscript;
    public RaycastHit2D onplayer;
    public LayerMask playerlayer;
    public Color coloor;
    public BoxCollider2D coll;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        pscript = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
        coll = GetComponentInChildren<BoxCollider2D>();
        coll.enabled = !coll.enabled;
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
     
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector2.up * size, Color.red);
        onplayer = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.up * size, playerlayer);
        
        if (onplayer)
        {
            Debug.Log("Touching Player");
        } else if (!onplayer)
        {
            Debug.Log("not");
            
        }
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! It was always returning true because it was touching the ladder collider. I discovered this by disabling all the gameobjects that it could be colliding with and the Debug.Log stopped working. But I got confused because I told it to only collide with my player layermask. The problem was that I had my layermask in the wrong parameter.

I changed it from this `Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector2.up * size, Color.red)`

Instead of multiplying the Vector2.up by size. I changed it to this:
`onplayer = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.up, size, playerlayer)`.

The size is the same and everything works great.